# Tkinter : "no such file or directory" error when trying to put an image on bg

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm working on a data base with tkinter, i have been trying to add a background image to my interface but i get the error : "no such file or directory"

It's for a school project, i'm in aeronautical engineering but i'm pretty new to python.

This is the part of the code :

```
photo=PhotoImage(file="background.png")

zone_dessin = Canvas(Fsur, width=1000, height=600) 

zone_dessin.create_image(250,250,image=photo)

zone_dessin.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is in the same folder of the script, then try:

```
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
imagefile = os.path.join(script_path, 'background.png')
photo = PhotoImage(file=imagefile)
```